# dllimport and templates in MS Visual C++

Tags: c++, function, templates, dllimport, dllexport

I have a class like this

```
class A_DLL A
{
   ...
   template <class T> someFunction(const T &v);
}
```

in library a.dll. A_DLL is `__declspec(dllexport)` when building a.dll and `__declspec(dllimport)` when using a.dll.

The problem is when I try to use 'someFunction' in some executable module linked against a.dll it works. However when I use it in some other library (b.dll) it gives me an error message about unresolved externals (someFunction and other templates). Obviously I should not use `__declspec` on templates but how then to make a class with `__declspec`?

Comment: This probably isn't the issue. It should make no difference that you call it from an exe or from a dll. Are you sure you're linking both against the library?

Comment: well both the library and exe use other functions from a.dll without any problems. By far the only solution I have is to make the template functions global (and add them as friends to the A class). This seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the declaration like:

```
template class A_DLL MyTemplateClass<int>;
```

This statement will generate the template class instantiation and export it in the DLL you are building (or import it depending on how A_DLL is set from preprocessor).

You could also follow this [link](http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2010/01/18/dll-export-cxx-templates/) for a more detailed description.